# Different instance of java.net.HttpURLConnection in multithreaded java application

Tags: java, multithreading, httpurlconnection

I have a multithreaded java client which posts data to a server and reads response using `HttpURLConnection`. Every instance of client is thread and they do not share anything even `HttpURLConnection` is not shared. (Every thread has its own `HttpURLConnection`) and it seem to be still not threadsafe. Could anybody confirm this behavior and what do you suggest as a solution?
By the way I have seen the similar question but that was asking `HttpURLConnection` was shared among different threads. Please note that in my case its not shared.

```
public class ESIHttpCaller{

private final String ESIHTTPURL = "http://localhost:7033/FBWS/eigBagHttpDispatcher"
private HttpURLConnection connection = null;
protected StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

public CBBag executePost(byte[] input) throws CBException {
    InputStream is = null;
    DataOutputStream wr =null;
    int STATE = 0;
    try{
        // Create connection
        URL url = new URL(getConnectionUrl());
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset="+encoding);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("encoding", encoding);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", encoding);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(getConnectTimeout());
        connection.setReadTimeout(getReadTimeout());
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        // Send request
        wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(input);
        wr.flush();
        //Get response  
        STATE = 1;
        is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,encoding));
        String line = rd.readLine() ;
        while (line != null ) {
            response.append(line);
            line = rd.readLine();
        }
        rd.close();
        return handleResponse(response);
    }   
    catch (Exception e) {
        closeQuietly(is,wr);
        throw handleException(STATE, e);
    }
    finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Caller code in thread like below :

```
        ESIHttpCaller caller = new ESIHttpCaller();
        caller.setTcid(tcid);
        return caller.executePost(outStr.getBytes());
```

Comment: Can you post some code? Primarily Where you open the HttpURLConnection and where it is assigned to each thread?

Comment: Posted my code, each thread initalize new Instance of ESIHttpCaller and call its method executePost().

Comment: Why is the StringBuilder `response` a class member? It is not threadsafe. If you use the same `ESIHttpCaller` instance on multiple threads you have a problem right there.

Comment: ESIHttpCaller is always newly created and never used on multiple instance. Caller code in thread like this:    cb.smg.general.utility.esb.ESIHttpCaller caller = new cb.smg.general.utility.esb.ESIHttpCaller();
//   caller.setTimeout((int)getTimeout4Channel(tcid));
   caller.setTcid(tcid);
   return caller.executePost(outStr.getBytes());

Comment: _it seem to be still not threadsafe_ - Why do you say so? What is the actual problem?

Comment: When I load test this client some of the request get (SocketException: Connection reset). When I send request directly to the server, no error occurs. I think this error because threads close others sockets may be ? (Althoug they have separate HttpURLConnection  )

Comment: I mean a Connection Reset usually means something "hung up" on you via a RST packet, which asks that you close your connection. So it sounds like you saturated the server or some gateway in between.

Answer (score 1):

Because you call disconnect() instead of close() on the HttpURLConnection.

From the JavaDoc of [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (emphasis mine):

> Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request but
>   **the underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be 
>   transparently shared by other instances**. Calling the close() methods 
>   on the InputStream or OutputStream of an HttpURLConnection  after a
>   request may free network resources associated with this  instance but
>   has no effect on any shared persistent connection.  **Calling the 
>   disconnect() method may close the underlying socket**  if a persistent
>   connection is otherwise idle at that time.

Comment: I tried what you suggest but no difference. still getting reset error on some requests.